# How mul instruction works in the case : 'mul mem'?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm an ASM beginner, I know that the mul instruction just works with a register or a memory.

Now, when we use : `mul var1`, how the value of var1 is retrieved? I think it  should go through a register first, right? But in this case, what happens in case all registers are occupied?

Comment: @stuartd: I viewed this post, it just says that mul don't work with an immediate value.

Comment: it doesn't "go through a register". The value is sent to the ALU along with whatever it will be multiplied with, which is dependant on the bit-width of the var1. Do note however, that this is invalid `mul word 3`, however, if you have the address of the mem that 3 resides in, you can do `mul word [varThatEqualsThree]` Grab the intel manual, here: [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's...](http://www.intel.com.au/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

Comment: The same way that `add eax, [mem]` works...  x86 is a CISC ISA, this is normal.  If you're wondering how modern microarchitectures internally implement it, see https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ and other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86 architecture does not impose that every aritmetic/logic instruction has to have its operands in registers. In fact, both operands can be registers, one to be a register and another one the effective address of a matching size operand in memory, or an inmediate value.

So, when a MUL instruction, other than one that multiplies two registers, is executed, it just takes its operands from wherever they are, put them in internal (not available for the programmer) registers, and perform the operation.

The exact procedure differs a lot with every evolution of the x86 architecture. Some CPU's do a register renaming: they have plenty of internal registers, and assign them dinamically to operands of instructions just dispatched for execution. Others use what they call "reservation stations" (Tomasulo's algorithm), in which the operands are stored waiting for a functional unit to be available.

Comment: "it just takes its operands from wherever they are, put them in internal registers". In this case, why not allowing "mul" to take an immediate value, put the immediate value in the internal register, and after performing the operation, mul clears its internal registers?

Comment: Who says it is not happening that way? But, anyway, why do you need the CPU to clear an internal register after performing an operation? Normally a register has a value until it is needed that it has another value

Comment: thank you, I just don't get it well, if it works this way, why can't we perform : mul imm ? ( immediate ). " I just taught about clearing because this process will happen soon or later, and because internal registers aren't accessible by the programmer, reserving values there don't bring any benefit. "

Comment: Register renaming is done with Tomasulo's algorithm, those are basically synonymous.  The options for holding the results of uops (like the load part of a memory-source mul, or the ALU part) are the physical register file like modern Intel and AMD, or the Reorder Buffer (like Intel P6-family).  The "reservation station" is also known as the "scheduler"; it tracks *un-executed* uops only; they leave after they're successfully dispatched for execution.  It doesn't hold operands.

Comment: See https://www.realworldtech.com/merom/ (Core 2 using the ROB to hold operands) vs. https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ when Intel switched to using a PRF.

Answer (score 2):

The named registers are for holding values between instructions, the ALU has internal registers where the values are held until the operation can be performed on them.

A value doesn't have to go from memory to a register and then to the ALU, it can go directly from memory to the ALU.